# Не выходит заполнить матрицу единицами

Tags: python, матрицы

Нужно привести матрицу к виду c тройкой как аргументом arr_matrix(3):

```
[
  [1, 0, 1],
  [0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 1]
]
```

С двойкой как аргументом arr_matrix(2), должна быть вида

```
[
  [1, 1],
  [1, 1]
]
```

Вот код:

```py
def arr_matrix(size):
    array=[[(x+y+1)&1 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if not(i+j)&1:
                array[i][j]=1
            elif i % 2 != 0:
                array[i][j]=1
    return array
```

Comment: а вы выведите на печать свой array сразу после создания. сразу увидите, что у вас не двухмерная матрица, и длина вашего array равна единице. вообще, не стесняйтесь выводить переменные на печать во время работы с ними - это простой метод дебагинга.

Comment: опишите логику заполнения матрицы. судя по комментариям, вам нужно заполнить диагонали единицами, так?

Comment: ваши исправления не помогли. вы не описали логику.  и потом, почему для 5 у вас матрица 3х5 в примере? и  какой результат должен быть для матрицы 4х4?

Answer (score 2):

1. Не создавайте матрицу копированием элементов. В противном случае изменение одного элемента повлечёт изменение всех остальных.
2. Если у вас двумерная матрица, то вам, соответственно, нужно два цикла, чтобы пройтись по всем элементам
3. В примере ниже элементам присваивается значение 1, если сумма их индексов НЕ нечетная `not (i + j) & 1`.

```py
def arr_matrix(size):  
    array=[[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]

    for i in range(size):
        for j in range(size):
            if not(i+j)&1:
                array[i][j]=1
    return array
    
print(arr_matrix(3))
```

**UPDATE**

После невнятных уточнения от автора вопроса, я переделал логику, исходя из учета четности/нечетности каждого индекса по отдельности. Опять же, без указания четкой логики заполнения матрицы, этот вариант - лишь догадка:

```
def arr_matrix(size):  
    array=[[0 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]
    for i in range(size):
        if (size%(i+1))&1:
            for j in range(size):
                if (size%(j+1))&1:
                    array[i][j]=1
        else:
            for j in range(size):
                if not (size%(j+1))&1:
                    array[i][j]=1
            
    return array
```

```py
print(arr_matrix(5))

# [
#     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
#     [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1]
# ]
```

```py
print(arr_matrix(2))

# [
#     [1, 1],
#     [1, 1]
# ]
```

Comment: Вариант с заполнением при создании: `array=[[(x+y+1)&1 for x in range(size)] for y in range(size)]`

Comment: @MBo судя по вопросу, я сомневался, следует ли проверку на чётность делать через `&`, а вы тут oneliner предлагаете...

Comment: С 2 кой не работает должно быть [[1, 1], [1, 1]

Comment: @СветланаРизина а вы описали алгоритм заполнения? нет? вот мой алгоритм работает с 2 так, как было задумано мной, а не так, как вам нужно. потому что из вопроса не известно, как вам нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вот в результате чего получилось, это решение удовлетворяет условию:

```
def arr_matrix(size):  
    array=[[0] * size for _ in range(size)]
    print(array)
    for column in range(size):
        array[column][column]=1
        array[column][size - 1 - column]=1
    return array
print(arr_matrix(4))
```

Comment: И что, вы не могли подтвердить, что вам требуется заполнить диагонали, когда конкретно об этом спрашивали?

Comment: я пока еще не разобралась с матрицами